# react-map-gl Warning onViewportChange

Tags: reactjs, warnings, mapbox, react-map-gl

I'm testing an example of the library with the version "4.0.0-beta.3" (https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl), but I have this warning to method onViewportChange:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is the component causing the warning, it doesn't seem as if there are any side effects in this render method.

Comment: @DimitarNikovski Yes, When i comment the method. warning is removed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved issue: Version 4.0.0-beta.4
https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/issues/642

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this on 4.1.13.

You can solve the warning by only responding to `onViewportChange` after the component has been mounted:

```
class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      latitude: -33.9249,
      longitude: 18.4241,
      zoom: 8
    },
    mounted: false
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({ mounted: true })
  }

  render () {
    const { mounted } = this.state
    return (
      <ReactMapGL
        mapboxApiAccessToken={<token>}
        {...this.state.viewport}
        onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
          if (mounted) { this.setState({ viewport }) }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```